# What is a best way to convert frequency data to samples numbers (integers)

Tags: r, excel, rounding, frequency

I have a frequency data of different alleles of a gene and total number of samples (1242890). To do the statistical tests (Chi-square, Fisher etc) I need the number of times allele was seen. What is a best way to convert frequency data the most accurate count of each allele (integer). Is there any function in R? In excel I have tried roundup, rounddown and round:

```
*Allele*    *Frequency*
Allele1     0.228
Allele2     0.195
Allele3     0.099
Allele4     0.04
Allele5     0.00167
Allele6     0.00127
Allele7     0.027
Allele8     0.117
Allele9     0.016
Allele10    0.027
Allele11    0.00031
Allele12    0.00725
Allele13    0.134
Allele14    0.058
Allele15    0.036
Allele16    0.012
```

Comment: What is expected output based on this example?

Comment: I'm guessing you just want to round the product of Frequency and 1242890? In R, `round(1242890 * Frequency)` That will give a whole number. What's wrong with the methods you've already tried? Can you give specific examples of problem?

Comment: I tried this in excel but the problem is after rounding the total count is never equals to 1242890, which is probably OK because frequency values don't add to 1. I thought there may be some better way which improves rounding considering total number

Answer (score 0):

Random dataset:

```
category <- letters[1:10]
freq <- runif(10, 0.1, 0.9)
df <- data.frame(category, freq)

   category      freq
1         a 0.3631365
2         b 0.7180477
3         c 0.2827611
4         d 0.8640651
5         e 0.7192371
6         f 0.5747942
7         g 0.3487860
8         h 0.4138134
9         i 0.3984429
10        j 0.1522889
```

You can apply a function across a column with mapply:

```
freqCount <- function(freq, sampleSize){
  result <- freq * sampleSize

  return(result)
}

round(mapply(freqCount, df$freq, sampleSize = nrow(df)))
```

Would for example return;

```
  [1] 4 7 3 9 7 6 3 4 4 2
```

You will never get a total count which equals 1242890 (from your comment), simply because the only way to get that is if each frequency count is rounded to exactly 1. This would mean that each allele would have been seen exactly once. Considering you are multiplying by a large sample size, even very small frequencies will be quite large. Even the smallest frequency in your sample dataset would be `round(1242890*0.00033) = 410`. Even if all frequencies in your dataset would be 0.00001, it would result in a count of `round(1242890*0.00001)*1242890 = 14914680`.

This all being said, why are you rounding? This would mean you lose a bit of accuracy. While I am certainly no expert in statistics, performing statistical tests on inaccurate data seems... weird. As far as I know, to run `chisq.test()` and `fisher.test()` in R, you don't need to round anything. Though, this might be a whole different topic and my knowledge on this is limited.

Comment: I thought about this earlier but I think rounding is better option because this is data of individuals and it should be discreet. So you can not have let's say 9999.7231 individuals having particular allele, it should be either 9999 or 10000.